# Confusion in Null Quantification

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I just started reading Mathematical Logic

**MY QUESTION**

[image: Language, Proof and Logic]

This part is from **Language, Proof and Logic** by John Etchemendy and Jon Barwise

They mention **"if the variable x is not free in wff P then ∀x(P) ⇔ P"**, then we can take **P= ∃x f(x)**.

But I saw in Kenneth H. Rosen's Book

[image: Kenneth H. Rosen]

They mention a **"quantified variable does not appear in a part of statement"**

Both Statement are very different. But both statement are for **P**, So should be same.

**Which Statement is correct?**

---

**P.S. :- Sorry in advance because my English is not upto that mark. Edits are welcome :)**

Comment: Follow to do what? Why do you expect two different statements to be the same? What contradiction do you think you see?

Comment: @DerekElkins both statements are for P.

Comment: $P$ is a meta-variable standing for an arbitrary formula. Right now your question sounds to me like you're asking something analogous to: "In one line in one book the authors set $x=2$, whereas the different authors in a different book write $x=3$. Which is correct?"

Comment: @DerekElkins Thanks a lot I got your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kenneth is refering to $A$ as the statement, not $P(x)$.   Like this:
$$\underset{\text{quantfied variable}}{\forall \underset\uparrow x~(P(x))}\vee \underset{\text{statement}}{\underset\uparrow A} \equiv \forall x~(P(x)\vee A)$$

So, as long as the quantified variable $x$ does not occur free within statement $A$, and the domain is not empty, we can establish rules for distribution.